# Передача категорий в Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

подскажите по исключениям Django
При входе пользователя, если пароль не верен в формах прописал
`raise forms.ValidationError("Неверный пароль")`  
все работает но при таких сообщениях не передаются категории в сайдбар

````
    def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        main_category = Category.objects.filter(parent_category=None)
        subcategory = Category.objects.exclude(parent_category=None)
        



        products = Product.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:8]
        myimage= MyImage.objects.all()
        randomProducts= Product.objects.all().order_by('?')[:10]
        form= ContactForm(request.POST or None)

        context= {
            'main_category': main_category,
            'subcategory': subcategory,
            'products' : products,
            'cart':self.cart,
            'myimage':myimage,
            'randomProducts':randomProducts,
            'form':form
        }
        return render(request,'index.html',context)```

forms.py

```class LoginForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].label='Логин'
        self.fields['password'].label = 'Пароль'
        
    def clean(self):
        username= self.cleaned_data['username']
        password= self.cleaned_data['password']
        if not User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError(f'Пользователь с логином {username} не найден.')
        user = User.objects.filter(username=username).first()
        if user:
            if not user.check_password(password):
                raise forms.ValidationError("Неверный пароль")
        return self.cleaned_data
    
    class Meta:
        model=User
        fields= ['username','password']```

не передает категории не на какую страницу
````

Comment: Было бы лучше если ты привел код, который у тебя есть. А то как-то сложно связать логин пользователя и дополнительные категории, которые у тебя куда-то должны передаваться

Comment: Обновил вопрос, Должны передаваться в верхний сайдбар

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил передачу категорий с помощью context_processors